# Deduce a number of position of number

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to extract number of position of a simple number :
Example : `123` is `3` position, `12` in `2` position, `12365` in `5` position ...
What is solution ? There is a method in `Math` ?

Comment: Common you can't be serious? Do you really want to count the number of digits in a number? And that too couldn't frame a proper question for?

Comment: Tip: [logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm), base 10 to be precise...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a String:

```
int numberOfFigures = String.valueOf(12345).length();
```

or take the [log10 of the number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10%28double%29) and round it up:

```
int numberOfFigures = Math.floor(Math.log10(12345)) + 1;
```

Comment: If you use the log and it's an exact multiple of 10, you have to add 1.

Comment: Also: [rounding up](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29)

Answer (score 6):

The robust way to do it is: `Math.floor(Math.log10(x) + 1)`

The `+1` is needed to deal with the case of the perfect power of 10. In fact `Math.log10(10)` is 1, but that is 2 digits long. `Math.floor()` will then round down the number to get the number of digits.